# How to sign a pdf file in migradoc?

Tags: c#, pdf, migradoc

I have a project that uses iTextSharp that I need to make it use MigraDoc.
the problem in question now is that I need to sign pdf files with MigraDoc (Or PdfSharp if need be), but I can't find any relevant info on this.

In iTextSharp I'm using this code:

```
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser cp = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser();
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain  = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] { cp.ReadCertificate(cert.RawData) };
IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(cert, "SHA-1");

PdfReader  pdfReader  = new PdfReader(SourcePdfFileName, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes"));
FileStream signedPdf  = new FileStream(DestPdfFileName, FileMode.Create);  //the output pdf file
PdfStamper pdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(pdfReader, signedPdf, '\0');
PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance = pdfStamper.SignatureAppearance;

signatureAppearance.Reason   = reason;
signatureAppearance.Location = location;
signatureAppearance.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION;

MakeSignature.SignDetached(signatureAppearance, externalSignature, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```